# All solutions of $p_y^k \pm p_y^t =p_x^m \pm p_x^s$ for odd primes $p_x < p_y$?

Tags: number-theory

Can we find all solutions of $p_y^k \pm p_y^t =p_x^m \pm p_x^s$ for odd primes $p_x<p_y$, whereby $k,t,m,s$ are positive integers?

There are at least two non-trivial solutions as $5^2+5=3^3+3$, and $13^3-13=3^7-3$.

Rewriting yields $p_y^k +(\pm p_y^t \mp p_x^s) =p_x^m$ and for larger values of $k,m$ the triple $(p_y^k,(\pm p_y^t \mp p_x^s),p_x^m)$  is an [ABC-triple](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~desmit/abc/?set=1). Using the database of ABC-triples, I found that for all values of $p_y^k,p_x^m < 10^{18}$ these are the only solutions.

This question is related to [solving a simple set of equations in radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508306/can-we-solve-a-simple-set-of-equations-in-radicals).

Comment: This seems very hard.

Comment: Trivilly $k=t$ and $m=s$ yield solutions for all primes. Apart from these, without loss of generality $k>t$ and $m>s$ and so the problem is equivalent to finding positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ such that $$p^a(p^b-1)=q^c(q^d-1),$$ which indeed seems very hard.

Comment: Following from observation of @Servaes, $(p^b\pm 1)$ and $(q^d\pm 1)$ are both even, and the only even factors on each side, so they must have the same number of multiples of $2$ in them,  i.e. $(p^b\pm 1)=r 2^t$ and $(q^d\pm 1)=s 2^t$ where $r,s$ are odd.

Comment: Back from lunch. Following from my previous comment and the analysis of @Servaes, since $p^a$ and $q^c$ are coprime, we can further deduce that $(p^b\pm 1)=r'q^c2^t$ and $q^d\pm 1=s'p^a2^t$.

Comment: I missed the time cutoff to add this edit to the last comment. If you substitute into the original equation, you get $p^a(p^b\pm 1)=p^ar'q^c2^t=q^c(q^d\pm 1)=q^cs'p^a2^t \Rightarrow r'=s'$