# On a power equation

Tags: number-theory

Given positive integers $m,n,k,l$ such that 
$$2^m+3^n=2^k+3^l$$
can we conclude that $(m,n)=(k,l)$?

I am pretty sure I saw this in the past and the answer is yes, but cannot remember how to prove it.

**Edit** Is there any way to show that there are finitely many non-trivial solutions?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Ty, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first answer was nonsense as @Clayton pointed out.

$2^5+3^1=2^3+3^3$

Comment: There is a resemblance with this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246446/all-solutions-of-p-yk-pm-p-yt-p-xm-pm-p-xs-for-odd-primes-p-x-p-y).